# Need Help Identifying Mistake in Solving Matrix Basis Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been trying to tackle this matrix problem involving finding bases for the column space and the null space, and I'm stumped by the results I'm getting. I've outlined my approach below, and I'd really appreciate it if you could help me figure out where I might be making a mistake.

**Problem:**

Given the matrix:
[ A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 5 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 6 & 0 & 6
\end{bmatrix} ]

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Applied row operations to get the matrix into row-echelon form:
   [ \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 3 & -3 \\
   0 & 2 & -3 & 3
   \end{bmatrix} ]
2. Continued with more row operations:
   [ \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 3 & -3 \\
   0 & 0 & -4 & 2
   \end{bmatrix} ]
3. Attempted to normalize rows for basis calculation, but something doesn't seem right.

I'm not getting the expected outcome and I'm doubting my approach now. Could you take a look at my steps and help spot any errors or oversights I might have made? I'm eager to understand what I'm missing.

Thanks a bunch for your time and assistance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtgXP.jpg)

Comment: I can't see how you got 2, what were the row operations?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley I have a link in the bottom of my post showing the row operations at each step

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with null space. We begin as you did with row ops

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&5&-1\\
1&2&1&1\\
3&6&0&6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&1\\
2&4&5&-1\\
3&6&0&6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$-2R_1 +R_2\rightarrow R_2$

$-3R_1 +R_2\rightarrow R_2$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&1\\
0&0&3&-3\\
0&0&-3&3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$R_2 +R_3\rightarrow R_3$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&1\\
0&0&3&-3\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$(1/3)R_2\rightarrow R_2$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&1\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$-R_2+R_1\rightarrow R_1$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0&2\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now we need the solutions of $Ax=0$ which is the same as $Bx=0$ where $B$ is the row-reduced matrix. This gives us the system

\begin{align}
x_1+2x_2+2x_4 &= 0\\
x_3-x_4 & =0
\end{align}

Solving for $x_1,x_3$ and letting $x_2=s,x_4=t$ be free parameters

\begin{align}
x_1 &= -2s-2t\\
x_2 &= s\\
x_3 &= t\\
x_4 &= t
\end{align}

So the solutions are

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
s
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+
t
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The two vectors on the right-hand side are a basis for the null space.

For the column space, do column operations on $A$ or row operations on $A^\top$ to get a basis

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&3\\
4&2&6\\
5&1&0\\
-1&1&6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$R_1\leftrightarrow R_4$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&6\\
4&2&6\\
5&1&0\\
2&1&3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$4R_1+R_2\rightarrow R_2$

$5R_1+R_3\rightarrow R_3$

$2R_1+R_4\rightarrow R_4$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&6\\
0 & 6 & 30\\
0 & 6 & 30\\
0 & 3 & 15\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$-2R_4+R_2\rightarrow R_2$

$-2R_4+R_3 \rightarrow R_3$

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&6\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&3&15\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

These nonzero rows are independent, so they are a basis for the column space.

Answer (score 0):

The third row of your second matrix, $\ \pmatrix{0&\color{red}{2}&-3&3}\ ,$ isn't in the rowspace of your original one, and it therefore can't be correct.  Subtracting $3$ times the second row of your original matrix from its third, however, produces $\ \pmatrix{0&\color{green}{0}&-3&3}\ $, so I'm guessing you've simply made an arithmetical error in your row reductions.